# Dynamically added class on a button can't be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a class to a button and then remove the current class. Now when I click the button again I want to remove the added class then add the old class. but It's not working. What seems to be the problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="cost">
    <div class="for-cost-button">
        <button class="btn btn-success cost-button">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function () {
    j(".cost-button").click(function () {
        j(".cost").addClass("show-cost");
        j(".cost-button").addClass("close-cost");
        j(".cost-button").removeClass("cost-button");
    });

    j(".for-cost-button").on("click", ".close-cost", function () {
        j(".cost").removeClass("show-cost");
        j(".close-cost").addClass("cost-button");
        j(".close-cost").removeClass("close-cost");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what went wrong with your code :

you have added two event listeners at the same time, when you click on your button, you are automatically clicking on the div surrounding your button so what happens is :

-you add a class show-cost to the first div
-you add a class close-cost to your button
-you remove the class cost-button from your button

- the class show-cost is removed from your div
- you add the class show-cost to the button .close-cost
- you remove the class close-cost from the button

if you take a look at the commented code below

you'll find that :

### -1st action undoes the 4th action then the 6th action undoes the 2nd action then the 5th action undoes rhe 3rd action

I have added a console.log to your code in order to be sure the events happen at the same time when the button is clicked

```html
<div class="cost">
  <div class="for-cost-button">
      <button class="btn btn-success cost-button">Click Me</button>
 </div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready( function () {
  j(".cost-button").click(function(){
    console.log(".cost-button is clicked");
     j( ".cost" ).addClass( "show-cost" ); // add a class to the first div
     j( ".cost-button" ).addClass( "close-cost" ); // add class close-cost to button
          j( ".cost-button" ).removeClass( "cost-button" ); // remove class cost-button from button
   });

   j(".for-cost-button").on("click", ".close-cost", function(){
     console.log("the div is clicked"); // when the div around the button is clicked
      j( ".cost" ).removeClass( "show-cost" ); // the class show-cost is removed from your div
      j( ".close-cost" ).addClass( "cost-button" ); // adds the class show-cost to the button .close-cost
      j( ".close-cost" ).removeClass( "close-cost" ); // removes the class close-cost from the button
   });
});
</script>
```